# please help me with this python beginner level problem. Please explain also

Tags: python, function, if-statement

DISCLAIMER - I am a beginner but have some experience in coding

If a filesystem has a block size of 4096 bytes, this means that a file comprised of only one byte will still use 4096 bytes of storage. A file made up of 4097 bytes will use 4096*2=8192 bytes of storage. Knowing this, can you fill in the gaps in the calculate_storage function below, which calculates the total number of bytes needed to store a file of a given size?

```
def calculate_storage(filesize):
    block_size = 4096
    # Use floor division to calculate how many blocks are fully occupied
    full_blocks = ___
    # Use the modulo operator to check whether there's any remainder
    partial_block_remainder = ___
    # Depending on whether there's a remainder or not, return
    # the total number of bytes required to allocate enough blocks
    # to store your data.
    if partial_block_remainder > 0:
        return ___
    return ___

print(calculate_storage(1))    # Should be 4096
print(calculate_storage(4096)) # Should be 4096
print(calculate_storage(4097)) # Should be 8192
print(calculate_storage(6000)) # Should be 8192
```

Comment: I see you attempted to add a code block - note that the necessary characters are three _backticks_ `\`\`\`` though, and not three single quotes  `'''`. Anyway, please specify in what way you need help here. Right now you just copied the problem, but what's missing is to see the code you wrote in your attempt to solve this, and at what point you got stuck exactly and why. There are four blanks, and for each of them the comment already explains what needs to be done, so it's a bit unclear what the problem is and what information is missing for you to help you out.

Comment: ok sorry , by the way thanks

Comment: Please see [ask]. For one thing, your title can be much improved. See also [why 'Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to your problem:

```
def calculate_storage(filesize):
  block_size = 4096
  # Use floor division to calculate how many blocks are fully occupied
  full_blocks = filesize//block_size
  # Use the modulo operator to check whether there's any remainder
  partial_block_remainder = filesize%block_size
  # Depending on whether there's a remainder or not, return
  # the total number of bytes required to allocate enough blocks
  # to store your data.
  if partial_block_remainder > 0:
    return block_size*full_blocks+block_size
  return block_size*full_blocks

print(calculate_storage(1))    # Should be 4096
print(calculate_storage(4096)) # Should be 4096
print(calculate_storage(4097)) # Should be 8192
print(calculate_storage(6000)) # Should be 8192
```

[EDIT]:
Explained the Code:
In the first step we basically used floor division to see how many blocks are fully occupied and then used modulo operator to see if there is a remainder!
Then finally we used the if logic to  see if remainder is greater (then we will need another block) and if so we take the fully occupied blocks and added one more block to them!

Comment: Thank you so much

please explain the code in if statement

Comment: In the if statement if the remainder is greater than 0 (which means we need more blocks) we multiplied fully occupied blocks (full_blocks) to the block_size to get the total block_size which is fully occupied and then added 1 more block

Comment: OK thank you so much my doubts are all cleared

Comment: Isn't this question part of Google's IT automation with python professional Certificate? I guess!

Comment: yes I have joined this course on coursera

Answer (score 0):

### Use floor division to calculate how many blocks are fully occupied

The `floor()` function will take a number and floor it

Example input:

- The floor of `12.24` will be `12`
- The floor of `26.999` will be `26`
- With `filesize = 1` , `filesize / block_size` would equal to `0.000244140625` and the floor of it would be `0`.
- With `filesize = 6000`, `filesize / block_size` would equal to `1.46484375` and the floor of it would be `1`.

```py
    full_blocks = floor(filesize / block_size)
```

`full_blocks` will be the number of blocks that `filesize` would have filled.

### Use the modulo operator to check whether there's any remainder

The modulo operator `%` will calculate the remainder of a division operation.
Example input:

- `10 % 5` would be `0`
- `12 % 5` would be `2`
- `293 % 32` will be `5`
- With `filesize = 1` , `filesize % block_size` would be `1`
- With `filesize = 4096`, `filesize % block_size` would be `0`
- With `filesize = 6000`, `filesize % block_size` would be `1904`

```py
    partial_block_remainder = filesize % block_size
```

### Depending on whether there's a remainder or not, return the total number of bytes required to allocate enough blocks to store your data.

As we've calculated above, if `filesize` is a multiplier of `block_size` (e.g 4096, 8192, 12288,...) then `partial_block_remainder` would be `0`, and there are no remaining bytes.

And the remaining part is just simple math.

```py
    if partial_block_remainder > 0:
        padding_size = block_size - partial_block_remainder
        return filesize + padding_size
    return filesize
```

### Conclusion

A quick look at your code, I've noticed that it is meaningless to calculate `full_blocks` as we don't need it, so your code can be simplified into this:

```py
def calculate_storage(filesize):
    block_size = 4096
    # Use the modulo operator to check whether there's any remainder
    partial_block_remainder = filesize % block_size
    # Depending on whether there's a remainder or not, return
    # the total number of bytes required to allocate enough blocks
    # to store your data.
    if partial_block_remainder > 0:
        padding_size = block_size - partial_block_remainder
        return filesize + padding_size
    return filesize
```

But if you still insist on utilizing `full_blocks`, here's the code:

```py
def calculate_storage(filesize):
    block_size = 4096
    # Use floor division to calculate how many blocks are fully occupied    
    full_blocks = floor(filesize / block_size)
    # Use the modulo operator to check whether there's any remainder
    partial_block_remainder = filesize % block_size
    # Depending on whether there's a remainder or not, return
    # the total number of bytes required to allocate enough blocks
    # to store your data.
    if partial_block_remainder > 0:
        return full_blocks * block_size + block_size
    return full_blocks * block_size
```